# Why is jstl's formatNumber currency symbol locale specific when setting currencyCode

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, locale

I'm using formatNumber as follows:

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${amount}" type="currency" currencyCode="${currencyCode}" var="amt" />
```

If I'm in locale en_US and the currency code is EUR I get `EUR` as the symbol, but if I'm in locale en_GB I get `€`. Why is the locale taken into account? Shouldn't EUR always convert into `€`? Is there anyway to get the behavior I'm expecting using `formatNumber`?

Comment: @jahroy that would change translations of text and formatting of the number, neither of which is desirable.

Comment: The documentation suggests you can set the `currencySymbol` to whatever you want: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatnumber_tag.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locale is taken into acount so the output makes sense to the user.

As a silly American (who lives in the en_US locale) I have no idea what that funky symbol means.

EUR makes perfect sense to me.

A [quick google](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatnumber_tag.htm) suggests you can set the `currencySymbol` attribute to whatever you want:

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${amount}" type="currency" currencySymbol="FOO" currencyCode="${currencyCode}" var="amt" />
```

Comment: Yea, the reason I don't like it is that means I have to come up with my own currency code to currency symbol mapping. I was really hoping that formatNumber would just figure it out for me automatically. Which it does, but only in the 'correct' locale.