# How to get currency symbol in JSP for specifc locale

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, currency

I'm wordering how to display just the currency symbol for a specifc locale and currency code (3 letters code: for example GBP) in jsp/html.

For example, with currency code GBP and locale en-GB it will displays £ (but the locale can change).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes the answer from Avinash will also render the value. If you just want to render the symbol, there are two possibilities:
1.) HTML £ (more on [currency symbols](http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-cur.htm)) 
2.) Store the symbol in the message.property file and add it with  to the jsp.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `currencySymbol` attribute  and set the value.

THE code would be like

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${amount}" type="currency" currencySymbol="FOO" currencyCode="${currencyCode}" var="amt" />
```

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419827/why-is-jstls-formatnumber-currency-symbol-locale-specific-when-setting-currency).

Have a look [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatnumber_tag.htm) too

Comment: But this also returns the value, right? I'm looking just for Currency symbol without any value