# Proper display of foreign currency values

Tags: java, localization, jstl, currency

Take the following example.

```
<fmt:setLocale value="en_US"/>

<fmt:formatNumber type="currency" currencyCode="USD"
                        maxFractionDigits="2" value="${item.zCurrencyAmount}" />
```

if item.zCurrencyAmount is 100331.20 then the expected output is shown as follows:

```
$100,331.20
```

However, what if I want to display Costa Rican Colones for an person speaking English in the United States (en_US)?  Again the following example:

```
<fmt:setLocale value="en_US"/>

<fmt:formatNumber type="currency" currencyCode="CRC"
                        maxFractionDigits="2" value="${item.zCurrencyAmount}" />
```

I would expect to see CRC 100,331.20.  Instead I get CRC100,331.20, the difference being that there is no space.

Is it a reasonable expectation that java locales should properly format foreign currencies (as well as the country currency), or is this a fundamental misunderstanding?  Is there a defacto or standard on proper formatting of foreign currencies for en_US and other locales for that matter?  AKA - is CRC100,331.20 the "right" way and what I'm being asked to deliver (CRC 100,331.20) is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If your locale is set to en_US, then the currency code gets displayed (no space).  So you'd have to add it.  However, if the locale was different, the symbol would appear instead, without a space, as you would expect.  See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106484/not-getting-currency-symbols-for-specific-locale

Comment: @NinjaCat Hello thanks for the response, however this doesn't get at the core question.  The core question is for the en_US locale, what is the proper format for non USD currencies?    CRC100,000.00 or CRC<SPACE>100,000.00 (CRC 100,000.00)?  By default JSTL does the one without the space, which i suspect is wrong.

Comment: Honestly, I would expect it to show XXX CRC, or as you say, CRC<space><Amount>.  I don't think that there is a proper format in the sense that there isn't a standard to check against.  There's a bit of info here... but it's not shedding light on this particular issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419827/why-is-jstls-formatnumber-currency-symbol-locale-specific-when-setting-currency

Comment: @NinjaCat - yeah I assume this isn't something that is actually thought/implemented through which is unfortunate.  The only way I think I can do this is to manually check to see if the currency (USD or CRC) of the current users locale matches the currency I'm trying to display, and if it does not, then output a custom format pattern of  pattern="#,### ¤" or pattern="¤ #,###" which seems like a hack.